# cakephp observerfield multiple updates

Tags: ajax, cakephp

Using CakePHP's Ajax based observefield, I would like to update multiple fields, into my form, any idea how can i achieve this?

If i try with `'update' => array('NoncompetitorEventId','NoncompetitorEventId')` it doesn't work even. It works for single field update, but not for multiple ones.

Kindly let me know if some patch is there. I'm using CakePHP 1.2 version.

Thanks !

Comment: I think, some users **must** tried this kind of requirements while their project development, but I wonder as no reply yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with little tweak using the `prototype` along with `observe field`:

Like:

Step 1: Call your function using observe field and call protype function on complete as follow:

```
echo $ajax->observeField('TransportorderContactId',array('url'=>'functionname','indicator' => 'loading_message','complete' => 'updateDetails(request,json)'));`
```

Step 2: Set the required fields in json variable in your called function:

```
echo json_encode(array('field1' => value1,'field2' => value2); //here keep your field name as id of the field you want to update.
```

Step 3: Now you will get the above fields in your updateDetails function which is in `add.ctp`

```
 <script language="javascript">
   function updateDetails(request,json){
        var data = request.responseText.evalJSON();
        $H(data).each(function(pair){
          $(pair.key).setValue(pair.value);
        });
   }
 </script>
```

And like this you can update more than one field using observe field.